# Vuex dynamic checkboxes binding

Tags: javascript, checkbox, vue.js, vuex

I have a problem with binding checkboxes using Vuex. On checkbox I use v-model with variable which has getter and setter to set or get value in store, the problem is that I get wrong data in store and I don't understand what cause the problem. Checkboxes bind to store property and this property must contain array of id's from checkboxes, but when I click checkbox more than one time it rewrite or remove store values. Can anyone help me to understand why does this happens?  [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/rempash/xfvphk91/67/) to jsFiddle.

The code

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
checkboxes: {},
checked: {}
},
mutations: {
  setCheckboxes(state, dataObj){
    console.log(dataObj);
    state.checkboxes = dataObj.data;
    let firstElem = dataObj.data[Object.keys(dataObj.data)[0]];
    state.checked[firstElem.parent_id] = [firstElem.id];
    console.log(state.checked);
  },
  setTreeState(state, dataObj){
    state.checked[dataObj.id] = dataObj.value;
    console.log(state.checked);
  }
 }
});


Vue.component('checkboxTree', {
  template: "#checkboxTree",
});

Vue.component('checkboxToggle', {
  template: "#checkboxToggle",
  data(){
    return {
      store
    }
  },
  computed: {
    value:{
      get(){ 
        return store.state.checked[this.checkbox.parent_id];
      },
      set(val){ 
        store.commit({
        type: 'setTreeState',
        id: this.checkbox.parent_id,
        value: val
      });
    },
  },
},
props: ['checkbox']
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data: {
    checkboxData: {
    ...
    },

  },
  mounted(){
    this.$store.commit({
      type: 'setCheckboxes',
      data: this.checkboxData
    });
  }
})
```

Template

```
<div id="app">
  <checkbox-tree :checkboxData="checkboxData"></checkbox-tree>
</div>    

<template id="checkboxTree">
  <div>
    <p>checkbox tree</p>
  <form>
   <ul>
     <li v-for="checkbox in $store.state.checkboxes">
       <checkbox-toggle :checkbox="checkbox"></checkbox-toggle>
     </li>
   </ul>
  </form>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="checkboxToggle">
  <div>
  <label>{{ checkbox.id }}</label>
   <input type="checkbox" 
    :value="checkbox.id"
    :id="'checkbox-' + checkbox.id"
    :name="'checkbox-' + checkbox.id"
    v-model="value"
    >
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please describe how you want the state to be organised. It is unclear what exactly `checked: {}` object should look like. Should it contain ids? Why is it an object not an array then? It'll be much easier to help you when you specify these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, assuming you want `checked` to contain ids of selected objects, I had to restructure your code significantly:

```js
const removeFromArray = (array, value) => {
 const newArray = [...array];
  const index = newArray.indexOf(value);
  if (index > -1) {
    newArray.splice(index, 1);
    return newArray;
  }
  return array;
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    checkboxes: {},
    checked: [],
  },
  mutations: {
   addToChecked(state, id) {
     state.checked.push(id);
    },
  removeFromChecked(state, id) {
      const newArray = removeFromArray(state.checked, id);
      state.checked = newArray;
    },
    setCheckboxes(state, data) {
      state.checkboxes = data;
    },
  }
});

Vue.component('checkboxTree', {
  template: "#checkboxTree",
  computed: {
    checkboxes() {
     return this.$store.state.checkboxes;
    },
  },
});

Vue.component('checkboxToggle', {
  template: "#checkboxToggle",
 computed: {
    value:{
      get(){
        return this.$store.state.checked.indexOf(this.checkbox.id) > -1;
      },
      set(val){
        const mutation = val ? 'addToChecked' : 'removeFromChecked';
        this.$store.commit(mutation, this.checkbox.id);
      },
    },
  },
  props: ['checkbox'],
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  data: {
    checkboxData: {
      "5479": {
        "id": 5479,
        "title": "Место оказания услуг",
        "type": "checkbox",
        "dependencies": "",
        "description": "",
        "parent_id": 5478,
        "npas": ""
      },
      "5480": {
        "id": 5480,
        "title": "Способы оказания услуг",
        "type": "checkbox",
        "dependencies": "",
        "description": "",
        "parent_id": 5478,
        "npas": "50"
      },
      "5481": {
        "id": 5481,
        "title": "Объем и порядок содействия Заказчика в оказании услуг",
        "type": "checkbox",
        "dependencies": "",
        "description": "",
        "parent_id": 5478,
        "npas": "54"
      },
    }
  },
  computed: {
   stateRaw() {
     return JSON.stringify(this.$store.state, null, 2);
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.commit('setCheckboxes', this.checkboxData);
    const firstElementKey = Object.keys(this.checkboxData)[0];
    const firstElement = this.checkboxData[firstElementKey];
    this.$store.commit('addToChecked', firstElement.id);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <checkbox-tree :checkboxData="checkboxData"></checkbox-tree>
  <pre v-text="stateRaw"></pre>
</div>

<template id="checkboxTree">
  <div>
    <p>checkbox tree</p>
    <form>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="checkbox in checkboxes">
          <checkbox-toggle :checkbox="checkbox"></checkbox-toggle>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="checkboxToggle">
  <div>
   <label>{{ checkbox.id }}</label>
   <input 
     type="checkbox" 
     :value="checkbox.id" 
     :id="'checkbox-' + checkbox.id" 
     :name="'checkbox-' + checkbox.id"
     v-model="value">
    {{value}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Using this code as an example, you can populate `checked` however you want to.

Also, a jsfiddle link for you: https://jsfiddle.net/oniondomes/ckj7mgny/

Comment: Thanks, your code really solve my problem, but can you give me a little feedback. Do I use Vuex wrong for bind checkboxes or it is Vuex  feature/bug?

Comment: Firstly, I am not very sure what the syntax for committing mutation you are using. Usually you call `commit(type: <String>, handler: <Function>)`. Looks like because of it you had a mess in your state from the beginning. Also it seems like you were only adding to the `checked` object, but never deleting from it.

Comment: Btw, Is it necessary to store checkboxes state in vuex? I would not do that personally. You probably should add a `selected` property to you checkbox objects or just store selected ones in `state`. The way it's done now is redundant.

Comment: I think it will not be superfluous to give a look to vuex docs to understand the core concepts. It's not a huge read. What I see in your question is a bit random.

Comment: Syntax for committing that I use, calls "Object-Style Commit" and it's from vuex official docs for mutations and it seems to me more convenient, but I check if the trouble in it.

Comment: Oh, it is indeed a valid syntax. Then you left with one major problem of not deleting from the state, I guess. Btw, I've made mistake. It has to be `commit(type: <String>, data: <any>)`

Comment: My major problem is the strange behavior of state, it can: not delete from the state, or rewrite(remove) value, or even do nothing. And I still don't understand is that trouble of my code or feature of Vuex. But your code still solve my problem, thanks a lot !

Comment: About the necessary to shore checkboxes - in my app I have set of checkboxes/radio buttons from api and I need to store their state, change it and update because they can have dependencies from other checkboxes or radios