# How to get Vuex to play nice with checkboxes that use an array?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm struggling to get checkboxes to work with Vuex. I have setup an example in [this](https://codepen.io/nidkil/pen/pGwQeY?editors=1111) Codepen.

I have defined my checkboxes like this:

```
<v-checkbox
  v-for="(item, idx) in $store.state.checkboxes"
  :key="item.id"
  :label="`Checkbox ${idx + 1}: ${item.name} [${checkboxes[idx].selected}]`"
  :value="{ name: item.name, id: item.id, clicked: true }"
  v-model="checkboxes"
>
</v-checkbox>
```

And these are the accompanying computed `get` and `set`:

```
computed: {
  checkboxes: {
    set(val){
      console.log('checkboxes::set::val', val)
      console.log('checkboxes::set::state', this.$store.state)
      const triggeredBy = val.pop()
      console.log('checkboxes::set::triggeredBy', triggeredBy)
      this.$store.commit('updateCheckbox', triggeredBy)
    },
    get() {
      console.log('checkboxes::set::get')
      return this.$store.state.checkboxes
    }
  }
}
```

The `get` and `set` get called, but the `set` changes all checkboxes on the first click and on the second click the `val` is null.

I hope someone has time to have a look at it and point me in the right direction.

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, for anyone interested I got it to work. I solved it with a wrapper component. Check out [this](https://codepen.io/nidkil/pen/qgjvWd?editors=1011) Codeopen for the solution.

This is the wrapper that does the heavy lifting:

```
<template id="checkboxToggle">
  <div>
    <v-checkbox
      :label="`Checkbox ${item.id}: ${item.selected}`"
      v-model="value"
    >
    </v-checkbox>
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is the computed property with the `get` and `set`:

```
const CheckboxToggle = Vue.component('checkboxToggle', {
  template: "#checkboxToggle",
  props: ['item'],
    computed: {
    value: {
      get() {
        console.log('checkboxToggle::value::get', this.item.selected)
        return this.item.selected;
      },
      set(val) {
        const check = val ? true : false
        console.log('checkboxToggle::value::set::mutation', check, this.item.id)
        this.$store.commit('updateFilter', { filter: this.item, check })
      },
    },
  }
})
```

And this is the store mutation:

```
mutations: {
  updateFilter: (state, { filter, check }) => {
    console.log('mutations::filterCheck::item', filter, check)
    const match = state.checkboxes.filter(item => item.id === filter.id)[0]
    console.log('mutations::filterCheck::match', match)
    match.selected = check
  }
}
```

The inspiration came from this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806053/vuex-dynamic-checkboxes-binding). It does it in a aroundabout way.